# Export database model from MySQLWorkbench to MariaDB PhpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mariadb, mysql-workbench

I designed a database model on MySQLWorkbench. Then, I export the model to generate a SQL script. Finally, when I import it in MariaDB PhpMyAdmin it raises errors like :

> #1067 - Invalid default value for 'created'

MariaDB version : 10.5.4

Do you have any idea?

Comment: a little bit more info about the error context would be appreciated. my instinct tells me, that it should be a mismatch between the column type of 'created' and the type of it's default value

Comment: Hi @user5482698, I'm doing a Forward Engineer on MySQL Workbench and I succeeded in solving the first issue about "created" column. Its default value "0000-00-00 00:00:00" was not accepted. So I ticked this option : "NULL ON UDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP".
A second issue appeared which is:

**Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') 
VIRTUAL,
`title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`description` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NU...' at line 5**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:

**create DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP**

MySQL refused the date to be like this: 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but just ran into this, appears Maria 10.5 won't accept invalid inserts even when ALLOW_INVALID_DATES is set in SQL mode, 10.3 would. I cannot find any reference of this in the documentation, but I can insert invalid dates in 10.3 and cannot in 10.5 on several server I've tested on. Dealing with this in an upgrade from 10.3 on a large database and regardless of whether allowing nulls is a good practice, it's broken a massive application as a result and we're bailing back to 10.3.